# Reading variable values from an external file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

The Objective: Bulk copy selected files from one directory to another directory on the same remote server by calling each filename into a Python script as a variable from an external file containing a list of the filenames to be copied.

The Problem: there are well over 1000 files I need to copy, so pasting the filenames into a list or dict within the script itself doesn't seem to make sense. I can read and *print* the filenames from an external file just fine.

```
def main():
    f = open("file-list.txt", "r")
    if f.mode == 'r':
        flist = f.readlines()
        for x in flist:
            print(x.rstrip('\n'))
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    
Output:
file-1.txt
file-2.txt
```

However, in order to copy the files in sequence, I need to loop through file-list.txt and have those filenames called as variables into an shutil.copy statement; but this is throwing an invalid syntax error.

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

def main():
    f = open("file-list.txt", "r")
    if f.mode == 'r':
        flist = f.readlines()
        for x in flist:
            shutil.copy(r"folder_1/"%s","folder_2/"%s") % x    
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
File "<ipython-input-3-223c95b85768>", line 10
    shutil.copy(r"folder_1/"%s","folder_2/"%s") % x
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I feel like I'm missing something basic, so any tips or advice toward a solution would be welcome!

**Solution** - with thanks to all commenters!

```
import shutil

def main():
    cleanlist =[]
    f = open("file-list.txt", "r")
    if f.mode == 'r':
        flist = f.readlines()
        for element in flist:
            cleanlist.append(element.rstrip())
        for x in cleanlist:
            shutil.copy(f"folder_1/{x}",f"folder_2/{x}")    
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How did you intend the `"` to be paired? There is one extra, or one missing.

Comment: The `% x` also needs to be applied to each string, not to the whole `shutil.copy( ... )`.

Comment: The answer to your question has been posted by mkrieger1. That said, I see a few places where the code can be improved otherwise. When you have the time, take a look at the `with` statement and how & why to use while dealing with files. The `os.path` and `pathlib` modules for file operations. And f-strings, assuming you are using Python 3.6 or above.

Comment: `r"folder_1/"%s"`  has an open quote, close quote, then... more characters and a _third_ quote. Do `r"folder_1/%s"` instead. Better, use f strings and do `shutil.copy(f"folder_1/{x}", f"folder_2/{x}")`.

Comment: Thanks, all. Will try these and respond later. I appreciate the quick feedback.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - `shutil.copy(r"folder_1/%s" %x,"folder_2/%s" %x)` gives me `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'folder_1/file-1.txt\n'`  @tdelaney - `shutil.copy(f"folder_1/{x}", f"folder_2/{x}")` returns the same error.  I'm new to this, so pardon any newbie misses.

Comment: Well that's another issue.

Comment: If your first code block works fine, why not replace the `print()` call in that code with a statement to append the filename to a list? Then you could iterate over that list of filenames directly.

Comment: Consider using *f-strings* and don't forget to strip off the newline ('\n') that you'll have at the end of each line. Also, given that you have so many files to copy, you might want to consider dealing with "chunks" of files in discrete threads

Comment: Solved! .. with thanks to all who shared comments.